# Creating larger matrix from original matrix with overlap columns in R

Tags: r, overlap

Imagine we have one matrix of 5*5 (25 elements)

```
m<-matrix(1:25,5,5)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

I want to produce large matrix with different dimensions from the matrix “m”
For example 5*8, now my second column of new matrix must have overlap with the first one and so on.

So bigger dimension (e.g 5*8) matrix would be like : (it is just example and not sure the amount of shift is correct)

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] ……………………[,8]
[1,]    1    4   7    10 …………………… 19
[2,]    2    5   8    11 …………………… 20  
[3,]    3    6   9    12 …………………… 21  
[4,]    4    7   10   13 …………………… 22 
[5,]    5    8   11   14 …………………… 23
```

In fact in each column we have a shift back to some elements of last column in order to prevent from reaching the last element of original matrix and producing NA value.
Please anyone knows how to create such a larger matrix?

The hardest part for me is to calculate the amount of SHIFT value regarding to the size of larger matrix. The larger matrix must cover almost all elements of the original one. (it is ok to miss some last elements)
thanks

Comment: Try to explain your logic along with code block you have tried...

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? As the proposed answer (and your own sample) suggest, there are near-infinite possible final matrices.  About the only things you seem to require is that `max(final_matrix) <= max(initial_matrix)` and that the column-wise ordering be monotonically increasing.

Comment: i want to find the best value of overlap which makes the last element of new matrix closest to last element of original matrix. that means  choosing less value of the best one produces NA and higher values overlook some elements which we could room in bigger matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the maximum efficiency of coverage is: (the best value of overlap)

```
> overlap<-ceiling(rows*(1-length(dna1)/(cols*rows)))+round(rows/cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but this might be helpful.

```
rows <- 5
cols <- 8
overlap <- 1
matrix(rep(seq(1,cols)*(rows-overlap),each=rows)+seq(1,rows)-(rows-overlap),nrow=rows)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17   21   25   29
[2,]    2    6   10   14   18   22   26   30
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19   23   27   31
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32
[5,]    5    9   13   17   21   25   29   33
overlap <- 2
matrix(rep(seq(1,cols)*(rows-overlap),each=rows)+seq(1,rows)-(rows-overlap),nrow=rows)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13   16   19   22
[2,]    2    5    8   11   14   17   20   23
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24
[4,]    4    7   10   13   16   19   22   25
[5,]    5    8   11   14   17   20   23   26
overlap <- 3
matrix(rep(seq(1,cols)*(rows-overlap),each=rows)+seq(1,rows)-(rows-overlap),nrow=rows)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9   11   13   15
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16
[3,]    3    5    7    9   11   13   15   17
[4,]    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18
[5,]    5    7    9   11   13   15   17   19
```

Comment: thank you for answering. but i want the program to calculate the overlap automatically based on dimention of new matrix, not manually assigning overlap variable. thanks again